# Why do I get warning "QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set" every time for a PyQt5 project

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyqt, pyqt5

I am using python 3.6.2 and using Emacs 25 for the development of a PyQt5 project in Ubuntu and it's running with root privileges. This works fine but I'm getting

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
```

from the command line for each run.

It would great, if you let me understand what this is and the possible solution for to avoid the same.

The code

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    # TODO: board connection
    self.comPort.addItems([str(port) for port in display_SerialPorts()])
    self.comPort.highlighted.connect(self.boardConnet)


  def boardConnet(self):
    baudrate = 9600
    port = self.comPort.currentText()
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port, baudrate, timeout=1)  # open first serial port
    ser.close()
    ser.open()
```

Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasised a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: Stop using root carelessly! This really ought to be an error, not just a warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure it is a pyqt or python related problem. Probably then running with root privileges you are loosing some environment variables and [`XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html#variables) is among them.

It's not a big deal since Qt is smart enough to fall back to reasonable default but you can preserve current uses's environment vars with `sudo -E <you_app>`:

> -E' The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment
>   variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is
>   specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the
>   environment.

---

**UPD:** instead of copying all your vars into elevated (root) environment (which may rise security concern), you can explicitly specify a set of variables to keep via `/etc/sudoers` file. Edit this file with `sudo visudo` command and add a line:

```
Defaults        env_keep += "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
```

---

**UPD2:** if you want to access serial device **without superuser** privileges add an your user into device's group (usually it's called `dialout`):

```
# check group
>>> ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 66 Aug  6 12:23 /dev/ttyUSB0
# add your user to a group
>>> sudo usermod -a -G dialout <your_username>
```

logout - login may be required after group change

Comment: I'm using virtual environment is that the considerable reason for this behavior.  Can you suggest me any other way to access the serial buffer without using sudo ? @9dogs

Comment: @NithinVarghese I updated my answer, check if this actually works because I got no serial device at hand to test it

Comment: This leading to another warning `QStandardPaths: wrong ownership of runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0`    .And this making program stuck

Comment: seems like you started your app from ordinary user, the app created `/run/user/1000` (it is `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`), then you try to run the app from superuser and got an error about wrong ownership. You can logout-login, the directory should be wiped out and recreated with right ownership automatically.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't Actually follow. did the solution work? I am facing the same issue with my code. What exactly I have to do?