# solve "qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :10 Could not connect to any X display." at CENTOS

Tags: bash, qt, matplotlib, ssh, centos

why SSH -X doesn't work when I run a Python script in a specific node of a CENTOS cluster?, Exist any solution without super user access ?

I checked other answers but I must use Qt backend in matplotplib

OUTPUT:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path '/run/user/11979', please create it with 0700 permissions.
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :10
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Comment: Does [XDG_RUNTIME_DIR points to non-existing path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55210561/) or [Why do I get warning XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981317/) provides an answer?